# java and auth0: Token signature invalid exception

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0, rsa-sha256

I'm trying to varify a jwt in java, I have used similar code to this post: *[Java - Auth0 JWT Verification - Is this correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581290/java-auth0-jwt-verification-is-this-correct)*

```
    public void parseJWTKey(HttpHeaders header)
    {
        try
        {
            Jwk jwk = getPublicKey(); //method to retrieve public key from auth server (identity server)

            RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey();

            Algorithm alg = Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, null);
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(alg)
                    .withIssuer("auth0")
                    .build();

            String headerString = header.toString();
            String parsedHeader = headerString.substring(headerString.indexOf(" "), headerString.lastIndexOf("\""));

            DecodedJWT dJwt = verifier.verify(parsedHeader);
        }
        catch(JWTVerificationException | JwkException | NullPointerException a)
        {
            a.printStackTrace();//TODO: Logging
        }
    }
```

but am getting the error: **com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA** I have also seen this post: *com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA* but I am not using HMAC256.

Although I can get the jwt:

*eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjdjNDM5MmMxMDA1MGJiN2E2MDYwMTVlMTk0MTNkOWMxIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NzE2NTU3NzEsImV4cCI6MTU3MTY4NDU3MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMTAwLjEwMTo1MDU1IiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly8xOTIuMTY4LjEwMC4xMDE6NTA1NS9yZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJjbGFpbXNhcGkiXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoicm8udGVzdGNsaWVudCIsInN1YiI6IjEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NzE2NTU3NzEsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwic2NvcGUiOlsib2ZmaWNlIiwib3BlbmlkIiwicHJvZmlsZSIsImNsYWltc2FwaSJdLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl19.oK4Cg2laKUgdAHpyZ3yB7bVlgdHevhkzQMn47wnQPbvc04GME90wXScHxTSNkgtTPnuXK_t-ddyPYrxOZFnHPfDr9PLTjDXilLF90Ga91a4khFvRqvTqRwXAnpsamAsBdXZoybkbQ8c_x7kPua5NwN13AJU_cL37tSuor4ujYIJ9McLdQDLIBhD7b76QAMF2UkstFG_oPUSwycot-18zuaB97K4b5X-rO-j2DfEy15caRmMGxX-1c4EMw4T4pxHkQc4WVumA0C2nsCufJ1ZyZ74bcebRTTbb9y__QDvekGa1vfUYG6Pon7q83gQVWiH580vwiH60rrICjl9fNK4hmQ*

I am unable to access the private key to check the signature on *jwt.io* as it is held on an identity server instance which is not under my control, however with my limited knowledge of oauth I believe this not to be the problem.

Comment: you should change .withIssuer("auth0") to your real issuer "http://192.168.100.101:5055"

Comment: Thankyou, I have changed it but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Is this the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750417/token-signature-invalid-error

Comment: Yes it is. I have sorted it now though. Originally the key in my program comes from header files and when i was parsing it, there where spaces left either side. A rookie error I think.

Comment: For me it was a mismatch in my jwksUrl and access token URL. Jwks URL is the one used for verifying the public keys and access token URL is from where you request the token , they both need to belong to same environment. In my case I was getting the token from stage environment but my spring security code was trying to verify the token with jwksUrl which was pointing to dev environment.